# How to hide the first column of a wxListCtrl in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

## The context

In a wxWidgets (version 3.0.2) C++ application, I am trying to hide the first column of a wxListCtrl.

I did not find a member function to do this so I tried to set the width of the column to 0:

```
myListCtrl->SetColumnWidth(0, 0);
```

first argument being the column ID and second one the width in pixels ([wxListCtrl documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_list_ctrl.html#ac5818d43ce3913f7f70a6a759485cd6c)).

After running the program, the header of the first column is hidden as I wanted but the data of each row of the first column overlaps the data of each row of the second column (which is not hidden). It is obviously not what I want. The header **and** the data of the first column should be hidden.

## The question

In wxWidgets 3.0.2, is there a way to hide the first column (header and data of each rows) of a wxListCtrl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can.  You have a few options.

1. Delete the column using `DeleteColumn(int columnIndex)`.  You aren't losing any data, just the display of it, so you can always re-insert the column and repopulate it if you need to re-add it.  Obviously this could be time consuming if your data is excessively large.
2. Depending on your application, just don't create the column in the first place.  You don't say **why** you want to hide it, so if you just don't want it, don't add it.
3. Implement your control as a virtual control which gives your application control over what to display where.  The burden of data display management falls to you to do manually but you have a great deal more flexibility.  Inherit the class with `wxLC_VIRTUAL` style and implement `OnGetItemText` http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_list_ctrl.html#a92370967f97215e6068326645ee76624

**Edit**:
To expand on the comment question, how to get the selected item index:

The wxListCtrl is a little weird when it comes to selected items.  I'm sure it has to do with needing to support report, icon, etc. different views.  When dealing with a multi-column report mode, you might find that you can only select items in the first column.  If you are on Windows, it should automatically be set to "Full Row Select" but I don't know about other OSs.

Anyway, here is a utility method that returns the first selected item (note that you can support multi-selection if you want to).

```
//Get the item currently selected
int ListView::GetItemSelected() const
{
    for(int i=0; i<GetItemCount(); ++i)
        if (GetItemState(i, wxLIST_STATE_SELECTED) == wxLIST_STATE_SELECTED)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

If you want (and it makes sense), you can connect the list item selected event.

```
this->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, wxCommandEventHandler(ListView::selected_Changed), NULL, this);
```

and within that event handler, get the selected item and do what needs doing (depending entirely on your application).

You will note that I'm using a derived class here which just makes things a lot easier but you don't have to.  You can connect to something like `MyMainForm::sqlResults_selectedChanged` or whatever.

There is more than one way to accomplish all this and you can also find some good suggestions and help here: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxListCtrl

Comment: I populate the wxListCtrl with the result of a SQL query. The columns headers can be for example "userID firstName lastName". I do not need (and do not want) the userID column which is the first column to be displayed in the user interface. It is the reason I want to hide it.
I still need it to exist because on a double click on one wxListCtrl line, I need to be able to get the userID stored in the first column  to do other stuff.
I will study your third point to see if it is convenient to use.

Comment: As a matter of recommendation, don't rely on your UI controls to be the storage for your data. Sometimes it makes sense (in simple cases), but generally it's better practice to maintain your data document separately and just let the UI be a window onto that data.  Keep you SQL query results in a separate list and just use the currently selected row as the index into that list when performing operations with the data.

Comment: I think I see what you mean but want to clarify a point. If in the wxListCtrl I do not have an index column but let us say only a "firstName" and "lastName" column which can be sorted in different ways and maybe filtered, how can I get an index from the current selected row?

Comment: @Mat.R, you can also set the user data for the column be it user id, row id or whatever. Or you can save the SQL results into the std::map based on the wxListCtrl row added. You choice.